# I dont understand why I am getting an error from shellcheck

Tags: arrays, bash

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

is_option(){
  for option in "${options[@]}"
  do
    if [[ "${option}" == "$choice" ]]
      then
          return 0
      fi
  done
  return 1
}

options=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5")
echo "Enter choice"
read -r choice
is_option "$options" "$choice"

if is_option "$options" "$choice"
then
  echo "Valid choice"
else
  echo "Invalid choice"
fi
```

Output from shellcheck:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 17:
is_option "$options" "$choice"
           ^-- SC2128 (warning): Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.
 
Line 19:
if is_option "$options" "$choice"
              ^-- SC2128 (warning): Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.

$
```

I figured "${options[@]}" would take care of the error.
My code seems to meet the standards in the correct example given by shell check:

```
myarray=(foo bar)
for f in "${myarray[@]}"
do
  cat "$f"
done
```

Comment: shellcheck is telling you that `is_option "$options" "$choice"` is the same as `is_option ${options[0]}" "$choice"`; how to addresss/fix this issue depends on what you need to submit as command line arguments when calling the `is_option` function; based on your current function definition you never reference any input parameters (eg, `$@`, `$1`, `$2`, etc) so it looks like your function calls should just be `is_option` (ie, provide no command line args)

Comment: While shellcheck warns you that you are expanding an array as if it were a scalar, your main design problem is that you are calling the function `is_option` with 2 parameters, but the function itself does not use any of those parameters. Replace the call by `if is_option; then ....`. Maybe shelcheck will then complain on the function definition of `is_option`, but this is something you can deal later.

Comment: That's what I thought but I noticed I could echo "$choice" for example after it was passed on the func call without pulling from $. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Your `is_option` function does not use it's arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc), but rather the global variables. This is probably not the intended behaviour. Also, when calling it you are not expanding the array with `"$options"` takes only the first element.

See code below. Note the use of arguments in `is_option` and different order of parameters - choice goes first, and then the rest of possible options expanded using `"${options[@]}"`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_option(){
  # take out first argument as a choice
  choice=$1; shift
  for option in "$@"
  do
    if [[ "${option}" == "$choice" ]]
      then
          return 0
      fi
  done
  return 1
}

options=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5")
echo "Enter choice"
read -r choice

if is_option "$choice" "${options[@]}"
then
  echo "Valid choice"
else
  echo "Invalid choice"
fi
```

Comment: Thats what I thought but then I noticed if I passed an argument I could reference it in the function without pulling from $. Like you can just echo $choice out in the function. Seemed strange to me

Comment: Im curious wouldnt $2 be the array and why dont we use that?

Comment: You can't actually pass an array to a function in bash -- you must expand it via `[@]` syntax and the function receives each item from the array as a separate argument.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. What exactly does it mean to expand an array and I suppose it would be better to use arguments instead of global variables? What would be the best way to use either or both?

Comment: So if I declare a variable or read one in after a function declaration in a script its still within that functions scope? Is this a Bash thing?

Comment: I understand, just now computed everything. Thank you for that. So it is best to use arguments generally speaking instead of global variables in a script like this? And, if I can access the value just by referring to it by name then what really is the difference. I suppose I should declare them all as local and I'm sure you can pass local variables?

Comment: I can't speak what is best (global variables vs arguments). Shell arguments may be a canonical way to pass arguments to functions, but variables allows you to name them. Not sure I understand your last question -- yes, you can pass local variable to function if you mean pass _the value_ of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not take arguments and you should check that

```
is_option(){
  if [[ $# != 0 ]]; then
    printf 'usage: is_options unexpected argument\n' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  for option in "${options[@]}"
  do
    if [[ "${option}" == "$choice" ]]
      then
          return 0
      fi
  done
  return 1
}
...
is_option
...
```